# What is a correct approach to implemement an AXI stream interface?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, axi4

I am designing several sumodules for FPGA and would like to interface them through an AXI stream.

Some of the modules I use are able to process the stream at data throughput speed same as clock one. Some are not able to process a continuous stream. Which means in the second case, the module is busy for a while (not able to accept data).

I have read that there exist some skid buffers or fifo between modules to garantee a smooth flow but I am lost when trying to represent it myself how it works.

My main concern is that the chain does not block or loose data.

Does anyone have an advice on the simplest approach to implement an AXI stream compatible module?

Comment: "not taking into account handshaking" but handshaking is how it's done.

Comment: If any one module cannot process data at data throughput speed your choices are: block, lose data, buffer that data, or make that module faster. If the data is continuous, buffering isn't an option (for any finite buffer size).

Comment: Without handshaking, AXI Stream doesn't make sense. The protocol is build around valid-ready handshaking.

Comment: I changed a bit my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you’re using Xilinx, Altera, or Microsemi, the FPGA tool chain library will have a rich set of modules for AXI and AXI-S, including FIFOs, register slices and other blocks for rate and width adaptation. It’s unlikely you’ll need to build anything at all, except for your own user logic.

Lattice? Not so much, at least since the last time I looked at them. They do Wishbone.

Now, what will you need to build yourself? It’s pretty simple really when you’re dealing with AXI-S. Your user logic needs to understand the TREADY / TVALID handshake. The key rule to remember is that the definition of a completed transfer is both TREADY and TVALID are asserted.

Do you need a skid buffer? It depends. You need one if for some reason your data sink can’t send a back pressure signal  (that is, negated TREADY) within one cycle. This would be the case regardless of using AXI-S or not.

Can your sources keep up with your sinks? Do you have situations where your sink can’t tolerate an underrun (like video refresh)? You’ll need to consider system response time to servicing these streams, and allocate enough buffer to cover that latency.

Comment: +1. And of course, negating TREADY is blocking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's more clear now in my mind

Comment: Do I understand correct that Lattice Semiconductor is just going about using Wishbone for their SoC type designs in 2022? As far as I understand, the Wishbone is supposed to be obsolete by now.

Comment: Wishbone doesn’t have a streaming interface, at least by itself. Yes, I complained to Lattice about the lack of AXI support before…